# Eclipse project get blanked out with an unknown reason

Tags: eclipse, project

I have not been using my computer for a month. Then when i turn on it and run eclipse, i find that all my project FILES are blanked out (0KB). Any ideas?

Comment: If you still have the project folder, look in _Project > Properties: Resource_ where the _Location_ of the project is (whether a subdirectory in the workspace or another directory).

Comment: @howlger I mean the actual project files become 0KB even viewing in Windows explorer. But this issue does not occur on other files.

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem by adding a file > 0 KB and starting Eclipse? (I don't think the problem has anything to do with Eclipse.)